# required a bean of type 'de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.AdminServerProperties' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i am having this issue of

required a bean of type "de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.AdminServerProperties" that could not be found

Consider defining a bean of type "de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.AdminServerProperties" in your configuration.

here is my POM

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--Add login page and logout feature -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Add login page and logout feature -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui-login</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--declare the admin server as a client, for self monitoring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

any idea what is the cause?

public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
private final AdminServerProperties adminServer;

public WebSecurityConfig(AdminServerProperties adminServer) {
    this.adminServer = adminServer;
}
```

Comment: Ed show us some code please. Where are you using AdminServerProperties?

Comment: public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AdminServerProperties adminServer;

    public WebSecurityConfig(AdminServerProperties adminServer) {
        this.adminServer = adminServer;
    }

Comment: Can you try to use @Import(AdminServerProperties.class) at the class level?

Comment: Or tell me this... Do you have these properties defined somewhere: pring.boot.admin?

Comment: And do you have @EnableAdminServer in your main class?

Comment: Hi @Faraz,  i remove the following from the POM and it works, thanks for the help
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: glad to hear...

Answer (score 2):

It will be enough add @Import(AdminServerProperties.class) above the main class (@SpringBootApplication)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).